# Is there an easy way to check if a website has an SSL certificate

Tags: python, ssl

Using urllib2/SSL?

I have a large list of domains, and it would be useful to know if any had ssl certs that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it. That allows more people to see that it's a helpful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about using `urllib2`. Unfortunately, the closest information I can find on this is [this link](http://wiki.python.org/moin/SSL) and the associated code:

```
import socket
import ssl

HOST = "www.google.com"
PORT = 443

# replace HOST name with IP, this should fail connection attempt
HOST = socket.getaddrinfo(HOST, PORT)[0][4][0]
print(HOST)

# create socket and connect to server
# server address is specified later in connect() method
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))

# wrap socket to add SSL support
sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock,
  # flag that certificate from the other side of connection is required
  # and should be validated when wrapping 
  cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
  # file with root certificates
  ca_certs="cacerts.txt"
)

# security hole here - there should be an error about mismatched host name
# manual check of hostname
cert = sock.getpeercert()
for field in cert['subject']:
  if field[0][0] == 'commonName':
    certhost = field[0][1]
    if certhost != HOST:
      raise ssl.SSLError("Host name '%s' doesn't match certificate host '%s'"
                         % (HOST, certhost))
```

Although the comments in the file are fairly extensive, the wiki in the first link also lists these instructions:

> To validate that a certificate matches requested site, you need to check `commonName` field in the `subject` of the certificate. This information can be accessed with `getpeercert()` method of wrapped socket.
>
> You will need `cacerts.txt` file that contains root certificates placed alongside the script - see below how to get an updated list. To check that certificate validation works - use `https://www.debian-administration.org/` in `HOST` name. This site's certificate is not signed by any root certificates from `cacerts.txt`, so you will get an error.

You could look into the [pyopenssl module](http://pyopenssl.sourceforge.net/pyOpenSSL.html/building-unix.html) as well, since according to the first link I posted, it can be used to validate SSL certificates in this way:

```
import socket
from OpenSSL import SSL

HOST = "www.google.com"
PORT = 443

# replace HOST name with IP, this should fail connection attempt,
# but it doesn't by default
HOST = socket.getaddrinfo(HOST, PORT)[0][4][0]
print(HOST)

# uses HOST
def verify_cb(conn, x509, errno, errdepth, retcode):
  """
  callback for certificate validation
  should return true if verification passes and false otherwise
  """
  if errno == 0:
    if errdepth != 0:
      # don't validate names of root certificates
      return True
    else:
      if x509.get_subject().commonName != HOST:
        return False
  else:
    return False

context = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
context.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_PEER | SSL.VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, verify_cb)
context.load_verify_locations("cacerts.txt")

# create socket and connect to server
sock = socket.socket()
sock = SSL.Connection(context, sock)
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
sock.do_handshake()
```

According to the documentation in the first link, you will need the latest certificate versions from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) for these examples.